# Calling stopForeground in a foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

Is it okay to call `stopForeground` at the end of handling an intent in a service?

The issue I'm worried about is if there were to successive calls to the service and one of them calls `stopForeground`. The currently running service call could be killed by android since there's no longer a notification attached.

Is there something similar to `stopSelf(int)` where I can pass in a startId?

Comment: stopSelf() will stop the service & stopForeground() will remove the persistent Notification from the status bar.